# Comparing null and undefined with booleans in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, equality, ecmascript-5, ecma

According to [ES5 section 11.9.3](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3) it says that

> If Type(x) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison ToNumber(x) == y.
>   If Type(y) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison x == ToNumber(y).

When I tried to compare

```
let a = null, b = null;

a == false; // false
b == false; // false
a == "";    // false
b == "";    // false
a == 0;     // false
b == 0;     // false
```

What I was expecting here, for `a == false` returning false is,  `false` is coerced to Number which is `0` so the comparison will become `a == 0` then for next coercion, which is of type `null == 0`, null should get coerced to `Number` which is `0`. So finally it should return true for `0 == 0`.

What I got from ES5 11.9.3 is

> If x is null and y is undefined, return true.
>   If x is undefined and y is null, return true.

Mentioned about null and undefined.

The 10th point of the ES 11.9.3 section says that if your comparison doesn't come in above 9 criteria `return false`.

Is my comparison returning `false` from according to 10th point in ES5 11.9.3 or am I missing something here>

Comment: `which is of type null == 0, null should get coerced to Number which is 0`. But `null` isn't of type boolean

Comment: "Is my comparison returning false from according to 10th point in ES5 11.9.3" - yes, i would think so. But there is no coercion to `0`, at least not from what i could see. As you mentioned, all points fail. PS: i dont see any reason to use ES5 here (you even tagged it as ES6?!), so why not [the ES2020 spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison)?

Comment: What specific comparison are you asking about? You only ever talk about `a == false`, so why show all the others?

Comment: I was just curious about null comparisons, so I mentioned all null comparisons in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fundamentally, yes, you're correct that you're getting `false` when comparing `null` with anything other than `null` or `undefined` because you get to the last step of the algorithm, which is `return false`.

If you're asking why `null == false` is `false`, the short answer is: Because `null` is only `==` `null` and `undefined`.

The long answer is in the abstract equality operation that you pointed to, here's the up to date version: https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison Steps 1-8 don't apply, but step 9 does:

> 9. If Type(y) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison x == ! ToNumber(y).

*(The `!` before ToNumber there is not a negation, it's a spec annotation about abrupt completions. This confuses people sometimes.)*

So now we have `null == 0`. None of Steps 1-12 apply, so the `return false` in Step 13 applies.

*(I should note that the "If Type(x) is Object" in Step 11 is not true when `x` is `null`, even though `typeof null` is `"object"`. The [Type operation](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values) isn't the same as `typeof`, Type(null) is Null.)*

In a comment you've said:

> I was just curious about null comparisons, so I mentioned all null comparisons in question.

Yes, you're right that you end up getting to the end. The only parts of the algorithm that relate to `null` are Steps 2 and 3 that check if one operand is `null` and the other operand is `undefined` and return `true` if so.